# JSONObject start from last key to iterate over the all keys

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have this code block that iterates over the all keys in my JSONObject, `jsonObject1` is a json object that has 1 key and bunch of json data as the value of this single key. So it look like this `{"singleKey":"{"anotherKey":"anotherValue"}, {"someKey":"someValue"}"}`

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(mystring);

Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject1.keys(); 
while(iter.hasNext())
    {
    String key = iter.next();
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(jsonObject1.getString(key));
    key1 = jsonObject2.getString("key");
    value1 = jsonObject2.getString("value");
    String place += "\n" + key1 + ": " + value1;
    }
```

What I want is, I want this while loop starts from the last key of the jsonObject2 and iterates over to the first key. So I will start adding to my `place` string starting from the last value of the jsonObject2. The first value of `place` string will be `someKey: someValue` (the last element of the JSONObject).

How can I start this iteration starting from the last key of the json object?

Comment: Use jsonObject1.keySet() to get a collection of keys, then reverse that and iterate through the reversed set? (if I'm understanding the question correctly)

Comment: @iaindownie could you write it as a code please? Default the iteration starts from the first key to last key, I want it last key to first key.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this (haven't fully tested):

```
public void jsonMethod(String mystring) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(mystring);
    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject1.keys();
    ArrayList<String> keySet = new ArrayList<>();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        keySet.add(iter.next());
    }
    Collections.reverse(keySet);
    for(String myKey: keySet){
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(jsonObject1.getString(myKey));
        // Do your existing stuff with jsonObject2
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "for(String myKey: keySet)" means?

Comment: It's a simple for loop, lopping through the jsonObject1 keys that have been parsed out to the ArrayList (which is called keySet in this case)